# Angular directive for custom validation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create the AngularJS directive, which should vilidate the form. The form has two inputs. The valid case is when the imputs are either both empty or both filled with any string value.

```
<form name="recipientsForm" novalidate>
    <md-input-container>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input name="name" type="text" ng-model="relationship.name">
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container>
        <md-select name="type" placeholder="Select your relation... " ng-model="relationship.relationshipType">
            <md-option ng-repeat="type in relationshipTypes" value="{{type.relationshipType}}">
                {{type.name}}
            </md-option>
        </md-select>
    </md-input-container>
</form>
```

The divective should be generic for other forms with such kind of validation.

My approach seems not working:
.html:

```
<form name="recipientsForm" novalidate>
    <md-input-container>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input name="name" type="text" ng-model="relationship.name" value="" empty-or-both-filled="relationship.relationshipType">
        <div ng-messages="recipientsForm.name.$error">
            <div ng-message="emptyOrBothFilled">Enter name.</div>
        </div>
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container>
        <md-select name="type" placeholder="Select your relation... " ng-model="relationship.relationshipType" empty-or-both-filled="relationship.name">
            <md-option ng-repeat="type in relationshipTypes" value="{{type.relationshipType}}">
                {{type.name}}
            </md-option>
        </md-select>
        <div ng-messages="recipientsForm.type.$error">
            <div ng-message="emptyOrBothFilled">Pick relationship.</div>
        </div>
    </md-input-container>
</form>
```

.js file:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .directive('emptyOrBothFilled', [emptyOrBothFilled]);

    function emptyOrBothFilled() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
                targetNgModel: '=emptyOrBothFilled'
            },
            link: function($scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                ngModel.$validators.emptyOrBothFilled = function(val) {
                    console.log($scope.targetNgModel);
                    return (!val && !$scope.targetNgModel) || (!!val && !!$scope.targetNgModel);
                }

                $scope.$watch('targetNgModel', function() {
                    ngModel.$validate();
                })
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: And you SHOULD attempt it yourself first.

Comment: Updated with my attempt :)

Comment: A simpler approach is to **enable** `relationship.type` only if `relationship.name` is set. You can work with `ng-disabled` and `ng-required`.  No need to build a complex validation and error messages for this use case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Directive's isolated scope object is undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211973/directives-isolated-scope-object-is-undefined)

Comment: You already asked this **exact** same question the other day: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211973/directives-isolated-scope-object-is-undefined.

Comment: I didn't get the answer that I'm looking for.

Comment: I think the answer is in the implementation.  The only model you have access to is the one for the element on which the directive is placed. Try `scope.$eval(attrs.targetNgModel);` to get the target element's value and I would use a watch instead of an isolated scope.

Answer (score 0):

An alternativ approach just using `ng-disabled` and `ng-required`:

```
<form name="recipientsForm" novalidate>
    <md-input-container>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input name="name" type="text" ng-model="relationship.name">
        <div ng-messages="recipientsForm.name.$error">
            <div ng-message="emptyOrBothFilled">Enter name.</div>
        </div>
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container>
        <md-select name="type" placeholder="Select your relation... " ng-model="relationship.relationshipType" ng-disabled="relationship.name" ng-required="relationship.name">
            <md-option ng-repeat="type in relationshipTypes" value="{{type.relationshipType}}">
                {{type.name}}
            </md-option>
        </md-select>
    </md-input-container>
</form>
```